# How to use Inner join on the same detail table repeatedly

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use TWICE inner join statement to get reference values in the same detail table.

```
Master table: bags_tbl
ID ...     bagA        bagB 
1  ...     121         122 
2  ...     123         124 
3  ...     125         126

Detail table: fruit_tbl
ID ...     fruit  ... 
121        strawbery 
122        apple
123        orange 
124        raspberry
125        pear 
126        pineapple


SELECT
bags_tbl.ID,
bags_tbl.A,
bags_tbl.B,
fruit_tbl.fruit AS bagA_fruit,
fruit_tbl.fruit AS bagB_fruit
FROM
bags_tbl
Inner Join fruit_tbl ON bags_tbl.bagA = fruit_tbl.fruit
Inner Join fruit_tbl ON bags_tbl.bagB = fruit_tbl.fruit
```

this throw error : no unique table/alias...
How to make SQL statement to get text representation of master table?

thankx a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    bags_tbl.ID,
    bags_tbl.A,
    bags_tbl.B,
    A.fruit AS bagA_fruit,
    B.fruit AS bagB_fruit
FROM bags_tbl
Inner Join fruit_tbl A ON bags_tbl.bagA = A.id
Inner Join fruit_tbl B ON bags_tbl.bagB = B.id
```

Comment: Right answer, but a little odd to use the optional `AS` when aliasing column names but leave it out when aliasing table names.

Comment: @Ted It's not odd if you consider it as the result of changing as little as possible from the OP's query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  You need to grant a unique alias to each join so SQL knows which one you're referencing in the SELECT clause.

```
SELECT
bags_tbl.ID,
bags_tbl.A,
bags_tbl.B,
fruitA.fruit AS bagA_fruit,
fruitB.fruit AS bagB_fruit
FROM
bags_tbl
JOIN fruit_tbl fruitA ON bags_tbl.bagA = fruitA.id
JOIN fruit_tbl fruitB ON bags_tbl.bagB = fruitB.id
```